# Storing values in SharedPreferences on button click

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How can I store already existing string value in SharedPreferences on button click? I have a TextView and a button: the TextView contains certain string and I want to store that in SharedPreferences on button click.

Answer (score 2):

To write it:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("Yourkey", textView.getText()+"");
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

And to read it:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String string = sharedPref.getString("Yourkey","default");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are methods which I use everytime to store data in shared-preferences:

```
     private SharedPreferences app_prefs;
     private final String DEVICE_TOKEN = "device_token";
        public PreferenceHelper(Context context) {
                app_prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(AndyConstants.PREF_NAME,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                this.context = context;
            }

            public void putDeviceToken(String deviceToken) {
                Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
                edit.putString(DEVICE_TOKEN, deviceToken);
                edit.commit();
            }

            public String getDeviceToken() {
                return app_prefs.getString(DEVICE_TOKEN, null);
            }
```

In the first method I create the shared-preferances object, in the second method I use it to put data and in third method to get data any where you need.